# Upgrade/Nexus Migration errors

Tags: ubuntu, open-source, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I am trying to migrate nexus from one nexus instance to another. Current instance version "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager - OSS 3.22.0-02" installed on "Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS" which is not supported any more in AWS, need to migrate this to a new instance with "Amazon Linux" OS and same/latest version of Nexus.

I already tried to setup a new instance and rsynced over the entire sonatype-work directory, but noticing dependency errors when the jobs are poined to this new migrated instance. though the packages referred in error are available in Nexus still internal dependencies of packages are referred as missing.

Am I missing anything on this migration or any refresh needed post data migration?

Sample error of a NPM job:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://\***URL**/repository/npm-group/@sideway%2faddress
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@sideway/address@^4.1.3' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'joi'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the log when you started the new instance?

Comment: I have not found any errors